# In PowerShell: Virtual environment can't be loaded. States that file isn't digitally signed. However ExecutionPolicy is set to RemoteSigned

Tags: powershell, virtualenv, executionpolicy

When I enter: Get-ExecutionPolicy it returns RemoteSigned yet I still can't activate my venv. I set ExecutionPolicy as administrator in powershell but it still doesn't impact my ability to run the virtual env. I have restarted vscode, and computer as well.

Comment: Can you post the exact virtualenv command and the error in full?

Comment: That implies that the relevant script file(s) hasn't been unblocked with [`Unblock-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Unblock-File)